# Why is my query method for my SQLite returning an error?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I isolated certain lines of code in my app, and figured out the line of code that was creating the error. The line of code creating the error was in my Main class:

```
 Cursor c=handler.returnData(name);
```

This method lead to my SQLite database's query method. The code to my SQLite database class(my returnData a.k.a. my query method is at the bottom):

```
 public class DataHandler {
public static final String PRIORITY="priority";
public static final String LEASTHOURS="leastHours";
public static final String LEASTMINUTES="leastMinutes";
public static final String EXACTHOURS="exactHours";
public static final String EXACTMINUTES="exactMinutes";
public static final String SETHOURS="setHours";
public static final String SETMINUTES="setMinutes";
public static final String SETAMPM="setAmPm";
public static final String ACTIVITYNAME="activityName";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="mytable";
public static final String DATA_BASE_NAME="mydatabase";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
public static final String TABLE_CREATE="create table mytable(priority INTEGER not null,"
        + "leastHours INTEGER not null,leastMinutes INTEGER not null,exactHours INTEGER not null"
        + ",exactMinutes INTEGER not null,setHours INTEGER not null,setMinutes INTEGER not null"
        + ",setAmPm text not null,activityName text not null);";

DataBaseHelper dbhelper;
Context ctx;
SQLiteDatabase db;
public DataHandler(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx=ctx;
    dbhelper=new DataBaseHelper(ctx);
}

private static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public DataBaseHelper(Context ctx){

        super(ctx,DATA_BASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try{
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public DataHandler open()
{
    db=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close()
{
    dbhelper.close();
}

public long insertData(int priority, int leastHours,int leastMinutes,int exactHours,
        int exactMinutes,int setHours ,int setMinutes,String setAmPm,String activityName)
{
    ContentValues content=new ContentValues();
    content.put(PRIORITY, priority);
    content.put(LEASTHOURS, leastHours);
    content.put(LEASTMINUTES, leastMinutes);
    content.put(EXACTHOURS, exactHours);
    content.put(EXACTMINUTES, exactMinutes);
    content.put(SETHOURS, setHours);
    content.put(SETMINUTES, setMinutes);
    content.put(SETAMPM, setAmPm);
    content.put(ACTIVITYNAME, activityName);
    return db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, content);
}

public Cursor returnData(String title)
{
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{PRIORITY,LEASTHOURS,LEASTMINUTES,
            EXACTHOURS,EXACTMINUTES,SETHOURS,SETMINUTES,SETAMPM,ACTIVITYNAME},
            "activityName LIKE"+'%'+title+'%', null, null, null,null);
}


 }
```

The log cat:

```
 07-28 09:15:07.589: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(29220): <ConfigWindowMatch:2136>: Format RGBA_8888.
 07-28 09:15:07.609: E/(29220): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
 07-28 09:15:07.609: E/(29220): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
 07-28 09:15:10.722: D/AbsListView(29220): Get MotionRecognitionManager
 07-28 09:15:10.843: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(29220): <ConfigWindowMatch:2136>: Format RGBA_8888.
 07-28 09:15:10.993: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29220): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 07-28 09:15:11.003: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29220): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 07-28 09:15:11.744: E/SensorManager(29220): thread start
 07-28 09:15:11.754: D/SensorManager(29220): registerListener :: handle = 1  name= BMA250 Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)--ef+8
 07-28 09:15:11.794: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29220): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 07-28 09:15:11.794: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29220): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 07-28 09:15:19.742: E/SQLiteLog(29220): (1) near "%": syntax error
 07-28 09:15:19.742: W/dalvikvm(29220): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41bf4438)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.daymanager/com.example.daymanager.ActivityInfo}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "%": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT priority, leastHours, leastMinutes, exactHours, exactMinutes, setHours, setMinutes, setAmPm, activityName FROM mytable WHERE title like%car wash%
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4953)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "%": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT priority, leastHours, leastMinutes, exactHours, exactMinutes, setHours, setMinutes, setAmPm, activityName FROM mytable WHERE title like%car wash%
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1013)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:624)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at com.example.daymanager.DataHandler.returnData(DataHandler.java:99)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at com.example.daymanager.ActivityInfo.onCreate(ActivityInfo.java:57)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5160)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
 07-28 09:15:19.762: E/AndroidRuntime(29220):   ... 11 more
```

This is my first time making a database, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: please make the effort of reading the error.

Comment: use a space between like and %

Comment: So it's near the "%". except I have no idea what's wrong with it.

Comment: hum, the error line is slightly longer. if you could be bothered to read it till the end?

Comment: Well, someone got me an answer below, to be honest, I would have had no idea that a space in a string would make a difference(plus a couple other stuff). Haha but thanks anyway.

Comment: the end of your query is `like%car wash%` there is clearly something wrong with it. it should be, at least `like '%car wash%'` (not the quotes and the space) or `like '%' || 'car wash' || '%'` which is a form that allows parametrization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'%'` in Java is just a quoted character literal and it gets appended to the string as is, without the single quotes. To put quotes in the SQL string, put the single quote in the double quoted string literal. Put some whitespace after the `LIKE` keyword as well.

Change

```
"activityName LIKE"+'%'+title+'%', null
```

to

```
"activityName LIKE '%"+title+"%'", null
```

Or better yet, to avoid SQL injection, use parameters like

```
"activityName LIKE '%' || ? || '%'", new String[] { title }
```

where `||` is string catenation operator in SQL.

Comment: so that's how you use like with `?` args. I always wondered, because using `LIKE ?` and `{"%" + title + "%"}` felt weird.

Comment: @njzk2 Syntactically `?` variables behave as literals and you just cannot put literals together without some operator in between.

Comment: yep, i figured that much, but i never made the link with the use of `||`. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Need a space between `like` keyword and parameter `%..%`

Change your method like this,

```
public Cursor returnData(String title)
{
return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{PRIORITY,LEASTHOURS,LEASTMINUTES,
            EXACTHOURS,EXACTMINUTES,SETHOURS,SETMINUTES,SETAMPM,ACTIVITYNAME},
            "activityName LIKE '?'", new String[]{"%"+title+"%"}", null, null, null,null);
}
```

Comment: obviously not. but again, the error it yields is quite a complete explanation.

Comment: Thanks, another answer gave me the fix, but im sure your code would have done the same. Thanks for the response!

Comment: For what it's worth, this won't work unless the single quotes around `?` are removed.

Comment: @laalto Yes I wrongly removed single quote around and now back with sql injection safe way. Thanks for your point.